# Every function in W^{1,1}(0,1) is continuous on (0,1)

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I am trying to prove that if $u:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ lies in $W^{1,1}(0,1)$, then $u\in C(0,1)$. Is there any help anybody can offer?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that your question fits the scope of MO. MSE (http://math.stackexchange.com/) would have been a better choice.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $u'\in L^1(0,1)$, you find from the Lebesgue differentiation theorem that
$$
\int_{1/2}^x u'(t) dt=u(x)+Cst,\quad x\in(0,1).
$$
As a result $u$ is a continuous function and the constant above is $-u(1/2).$

Comment: that's it. it could be additionally mentioned that $W^{1,1}$-functions are also absolutely continuous.